# IPv6 routes mysteriously disappearing on Linux

Tags: linux, routing, ipv6, wireguard

I have a complex routing setup involving an IPv6 /64 routed over Wireguard. Both ends of the wg tunnel are configured as routers (forwarding=1) and not running any automated network device management (no desktop software, no NetworkManager, no systemd, no DHCP, etc.) beyond what the Linux kernel does.

Yesterday, I found v6 connectivity down, and after spending a while looking at tcpdump at various points along the route, I inspected the routing tables, and found that, on both ends, the manually-added routes were gone! (On one end, it was the route to the /64; on the other end, it was a route to ::/0, i.e. default route, that had disappeared.) Neither end has been rebooted in months, nor had any root logins during the time the routes went from working to gone.

I assume there's some sort of kernel-level autoconfiguration going on where it can decide  a route is no longer appropriate or dead and remove it, but I haven't been able to find any documentation on this. What settings could cause this, and how can I disable it so it doesn't happen again? I would very much prefer static settings that prevent all dynamic changes rather than needing some sort of process to babysit it and add back the routes if they get removed.

Comment: Perhaps the wg option of `Table = off` ? See [example link](https://shibumi.dev/posts/disable-routing-for-wireguard/).

Comment: @harrymc: I'm not using wg-quick, just direct wg command. But I'll see if there's something related. Still not sure why it would happen dynamically months after the interface was configured.